# Faster android screenshotting with an emulator

Tags: c#, android, adb, bluestacks

I have been struggling to find a way to efficiently take/pull screenshots from a android emulator (BlueStacks 4), My project goal is to automate a game process using Template Matching with OpenCV, therefore i need semi-fast screenshot pulling.

I have tried:

- ADB Screenshot (Way too slow)
- ADB Screenshot to binary (too slow)

If there are any other ideas, it would be a great help!

Kind Regards,
Jack.

Comment: Please take a look to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75145123/16096952.

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you just mirror your real device to your computer screen using something like Vysor

This could help

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Although i would like to use something like this.. I don't know how i could. I need to be able to use tap input capability.

Comment: I Think it possible with this tool. Because you will be using your real device while capturing either your computer screen or device screen.